# Long site name hides the diamond in profile page Communities

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, moderators

Normally we see the sites where the user has a diamond in the Communities section of their profile:

> [image]

However, when the site name is lengthy and causes text overflow, the diamond is hidden:

> [image]

(The [above user](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/187/joetaxpayer) is a moderator on Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange)

Can this please be fixed so that we'll see the diamond regardless of the site name length?

Comment: Looks like putting the diamond _before_ the site might be a reasonable fix?

Comment: @Jenayah that would look weird at first, but yeah... reasonable compromise indeed.

Comment: Why the diamond is matter, but site name tail isn’t? The better solution would be to wraps long names into several lines.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ because the site name is mostly unambiguous with icon and (maybe only) name being shown. The diamond is not.

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard in general I see no reason why the diamond is needed here in that list. Why it's important to know that user is moderator of any other sites other than current one.

Comment: I suspect that not every browser shows the same result due to fonts and which CSS is supported and included in the render list, also rep width comes into play. There should simply be an area left of the rep but measures from the right margin where the diamond simply overlays the tail of the sites name (even if it stomps on any "...") since it's more important to see the diamond(s) than the full name or any ellipses. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZQE3.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue has been fixed:

> [image: Image showing diamond regardless of long site name]

The diamond ♦ is shown regardless of the length of the site name.