# Diamond on moderator profile page is hidden if the site has a long name

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, moderators

On the moderator [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/260198?tab=profile) there were a diamond alongside sites they are moderating.

> [image]

It's hidden if the site name is too long. Is it a bug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Long site name hides the diamond in profile page Communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326904/long-site-name-hides-the-diamond-in-profile-page-communities)

Comment: @Jenayah yep, that's it.

Comment: @Jenayah but I [can't press "Submit" on this dup suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340864/260198) D: