# Nothing happens when I press "Submit" on duplicate suggestion

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, duplicate-suggestions

For example, in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340863/260198).

> [image]

Comment: Have you checked if your browser logs an issue or if the request is sent and what the response is? (press f12 to open the developer and check "console" and "network")

Comment: @Tom 1) There were no errors in console. 2) The network request wasn't even sent. Completely nothing has happened.

Comment: Then it looks like the button isn't linked to any action. We had a similar issue in the reopen queue: [New Dialog-Box in Reopen Votes Review Queue Doesn't Close](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/338097) ... let's wait for the fix :D

Comment: Possibly it didn't load all the script/content.  Did you try refreshing the page?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm yes, I've tried to refresh/reopen.

Comment: I've encountered this situation too; [the original question is missing in the banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339805/295232).

Comment: I also had this issue

Comment: Also it occurred in the same issue of our site. - [Bug report on ja.SO meta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3185)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed.

There had been one part of the code that was getting the duplicate selections, and another where it was only showing the duplicate selections if they had an answer. So if there was only one suggestion and it didn't have an answer, you would see the notice but would not be given anything to choose from.

Has been fixed to show all duplicate suggestions even if they don't have an answer.

Comment: Ah, yet another instance of the duplicate closure code that fails to consider the possibility of unanswered targets...there are many, many more. Two examples: the duplicate selection box search incorrectly excludes unanswered questions on meta sites, and the Roomba code deletes unanswered duplicate targets (while blocking normal users, including moderators, from deleting). Can those please be fixed?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog if you want to report another issue, please do so in another post or posts

Comment: There are already existing posts for those; I just forgot to link to those in my comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284733/show-unanswered-questions-in-the-duplicate-dialog-in-cases-where-its-possible-t?r=SearchResults&s=1|62.3845 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310298/377214

Comment: @YaakovEllis, Issue related to the same https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342500/484288